# Uncaught TypeError: cannot read 'hasClass' property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, hierarchy

I need to read the class of a selected list item in an 'onClick' Listener. This element is relative to the button as I have multiple instances (quiz items on a test). I try to do so in http://jsfiddle.net/nimsson/5fW2Z/12/.
The error occurs in

```
$("ul.quiz div.quizitem div.nav span.next").click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).parent().parent().children("ul.answers li.selected")[0].hasClass("correct") ? "Correct":"Wrong");
});
```

The html hiearchy is

```
<ul class="quiz">
        <li>
            <div class="quizitem">
                <div class="question">What is 2+2?</div>
                <br />
                <ul class="answers">
                   <li class="wrong answer">a. 5</li>
                   <li class="wrong answer">b. 2</li>
                   <li class="correct answer">c. 4</li>
                </ul>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="nav"><span class="prev">Previous</span><span class="next">Next</span></div>
            </div> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="quizitem">
                <div class="question">What is 2+2?</div>
                <br />
                <ul class="answers">
                   <li class="wrong answer">a. 5</li>
                   <li class="wrong answer">b. 2           </li>
                   <li class="correct answer">c. 4</li>
                </ul>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="nav"><span class="prev">Previous</span><span class="next">Next</span></div>
            </div> 
        </li>
    </ul>
```

What have I done wrong? I do believe that I have the hiearchy correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect selector for targeting selected li in next button click event. You do not need to convert the object to javascript object as you need to use `.hasClass()` method. also you can narrow down your selector to use `.closest()` insteads of using `.parent()` multiple times.Use:

```
$(this).closest('.quizitem').find("ul.answers li.selected").hasClass("correct") ? "Correct":"Wrong")
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkLhna7w/)**

Answer (score 3):

`$(this).parent().parent().children("ul.answers li.selected")[0]` returns a dom element not a jQuery object which does not have [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method..

So

```
$(this).parent().parent().children("ul.answers li.selected").eq(0).hasClass('correct')
```

If you have more than 1 element with `li.selected` selector only then you have to use the `eq()` else you can just say `.children("ul.answers li.selected").hasClass('correct')`